# Elasticsearch match element in array

Tags: elasticsearch

Given this data:

```
[
  {
    "tags": [
      "food"
    ]
  },
  {
    "tags": [
      "food features"
    ]
  }
]
```

And index mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I build a query that returns matched tags **[food]** and **[food features]** when I searched for **[food]** tag,  but when I search for **food features** tag, only **[food features]** tag is returned?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) on the `tags.keyword` field could do the job:

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "tags.keyword": "food"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in case of the index with a document with tags: [food features A], this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you update your question with a sample document and the query you think won't work?